# How can i set a CommandText to my Search Button?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to make a search button that when i enter an ID to a Textbox and press it , it goes to my private SQL server database and get the data row referred to that ID , But The exception handler brings me error because of my wrong CommandText .. Here is my Code

```
private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   cn.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConStr;
   if (ID.Text == "")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please Enter The ID you would like to search");
   }
   else
   {
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
      cn.Open();
      SqlParameter user = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
      SqlParameter FN = new SqlParameter("@First_Name",SqlDbType.NChar);
      SqlParameter LN = new SqlParameter("@Last_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      SqlParameter Jb = new SqlParameter("@Job", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      SqlParameter Ag = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      SqlParameter ph = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
      com.Parameters.Add(user);
      com.Parameters.Add(FN);
      com.Parameters.Add(LN);
      com.Parameters.Add(Jb);
      com.Parameters.Add(Ag);
      com.Parameters.Add(ph);

      com.Connection = cn;
```

Here is my Error : 
                ***com.CommandText = "Search (First_Name,Last_Name,Job,Age,Phone) values('" + FN + "','" + LN + "','" + Jb+ "','" + Ag + "','" + ph + "' from MyList) ";***

```
      user.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
      FN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      LN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      Jb.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      Ag.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      ph.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

      FN.Size = 10;
      LN.Size = 10;
      Jb.Size = 10;
      Ag.Size = 10;
      ph.Size = 10;

      user.Value = Convert.ToInt32(ID.Text);

      try
      {
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();

         FirstName.Text = FN.Value.ToString();
         LastName.Text = LN.Value.ToString();
         Job.Text = Jb.Value.ToString();
         Age.Text = Ag.Value.ToString();
         Phone.Text = ph.Value.ToString();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
         cn.Close();
      }
```

I'm Using Visual Studio 2012 .
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Search (First_Name,Last_Name,Job,Age,Phone) values('" + FN + "','" + LN + "','" + Jb+ "','" + Ag + "','" + ph + "' from MyList)"
```

doesn't really look like SQL. Also I'm not quite sure why you're setting loads of parameters you're not using.

Maybe you meant something like

```
com.CommandText = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Job, Age, Phone FROM MyList WHERE ID=@Id";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID.Text);
```

Furthermore if that's your intention, then `ExecuteNonQuery` is wrong as that's for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and other things that don't return a result.

Comment: @Joey I want the output be set each in a different text box on the form , the parameters doesn't support this operation ?

Comment: The parameters is to prevent injection and doesn't have to do with what is output.

Answer (score 1):

Command text should be like

```
com.CommandText = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Job, Age, Phone FROM MyList WHERE ....";
```

Remove most of your parameters, leave only input ones.

Instead of `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` use: `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` and using it read your data. Example article is [here](http://www.agilechai.com/content/archive/2007/06/09/how-to-use-sqldatareader-plus-source-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

```
"Search (First_Name,Last_Name,Job,Age,Phone) values('" + FN + "','" + LN + "','" + Jb+ "','" + Ag + "','" + ph + "' from MyList)"
```

Doesn't look like valid SQL to me.

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```
 using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
 {
    string oString = " SELECT  * from MyList WHERE (id = @id)";
    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
    oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", ID.Text));

    myConnection.Open();
    string name="";
    string lastname ="";
    using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (oReader.Read())
       {
          name  = oReader["name"].ToString(); // replace "name" with the name of the column you want
          lastname = oReader["lastname"].ToString();
       }
    }
    myConnection.Close();
    return name + lastname;
```

You can use these values to set the text in your textboxes on your form:

```
YourNameTextbox.Text = name;
```

.. etc